# Java - How to set the height and width of the component using box layout

Tags: java, applet

I am creating the applet using the BoxLayout. In this layout i have 3 components(i.e, 2 text areas and one button). I want to set the height and width of the button.Please can anybody help me.

code

```
public class parsetextdata extends Applet
{   

    TextArea ta1,ta2;
    Button parse;
    public void init() 
    {       
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ta1 = new TextArea();       
        add(ta1); 

        parse = new Button();
        parse.setLabel("parse");
        parse.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        parse.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(parse);

        ta2 = new TextArea(); 
        ta2.setEditable(false);
        ta2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        ta2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(ta2);                                       
        }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `parse.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, x))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add the `JButton` directly. Instead, add it to a `JPanel`, and then add that `JPanel` to the applet's content pane. The reason for this is the layout manager of the applet's content pane is causing the components to take up as much space as possible. By adding the button to the panel first, and then adding the panel to the applet's content pane, the panel will be resized and the button will keep it's preferred size.

**EDIT -**

I just noticed that you're using AWT components. Therefore, here are the component translations:

- `JButton` = `Button`
- `JPanel` = `Panel`